# Create runnable and minimal jar in Intellij IDEA ( auto select necessary third party jars needed by the main class)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, proguard, executable-jar

I have 2 modules in IntelliJ IDEA, one is the common classes used by all my java project, the other is the project's unique classes.

Usually, the unique project module **only use few classes** in the commonclass module. If I create a runnable jar in project module, it will include **all the third party** jars used in commonclass modules in spite of the jars are actually used by the main class.

ps: as showed in [here](http://7xi4pf.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/stackoverflow/min-jars.png), most dependencies are used by classes in commonclass which are not used by WordFreqSort module(where the main class locate). I can remove the useless jars manually.

Is there a method that third part jars are automatically included based on the main class?

Comment: Don't do this in the IDE directly -- use maven instead.

Comment: Try to use maven but come up with thr problem: use commonclass module/project  as dependences( with **systemPath** info) of the second project. However, I have to re-packaging commonclass module to generate the up-to-date commonclass.jar file each time before packaging second project. What's more, the second project packaging failed because of using comonclass's class segment.class without stanford.jar, this third party jar is only included in commonclass's pom.xml, not in second project's pom.xml. Could you give me some help ?

Comment: With maven you can use 'dependency exclusions' to solve the problem of pulling in unused libs. The stanford lib should be included as a transitive dependency when you include the common lib. Do not, ever, use 'system' dependencies. Depend on a version of your standard lib available from some common repo -- it that's not available then you have bigger problems.